# how to use composite entities which driven by different persistence unit via using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, persistence-unit

There are 2 different persistence unit in my project. 
PU_A: Application entities, that can execute all crud operations.
PU_B: This one has some views which contains outside data. I can just read data from here

But i want to create foreign key in some entities which are in PU_A by using immutable-entity which managed by PU_B persistence-unit.

If you could view on following snippets. I have IncomingPaperwork entity which is driven by PU_A and ProjectView which is driven by PU_B. 
After i applied this issue; When deploy the application exception that is below occured :

```
30-Jan-2013 15:13:05 o'clock EET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule$1.execute(EJBModule.java:326)
    at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitRegistryInitializer.setupPersistenceUnitRegistries(PersistenceUnitRegistryInitializer.java:62)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.initPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:411)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:365)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.acme.model.entity.IncomingPaperwork.projectView references an unknown entity: com.acme.integrationmodel.entity.ProjectView
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processEndOfQueue(AnnotationConfiguration.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(AnnotationConfiguration.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1162)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
[03:13:05 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

***persistence.xml***

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="PU_A" transaction-type="JTA">
      <description>This unit manages all application entities</description>
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>jdbc/A_DS</jta-data-source>
      <class>com.acme.model.entity.IncomingPaperwork</class>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.jndi.url" value="t3://localhost:7101"/>
         <!--DataSource-->
         <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource"
                   value="jdbc/A_DS"/>
         <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                   value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                   value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
         <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="jar,class"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
   <persistence-unit name="PU_B" transaction-type="JTA">
      <description>This unit manages all integration entities</description>
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>jdbc/B_DS</jta-data-source>
      <class>com.acme.integrationmodel.entity.ProjectView</class>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.jndi.url" value="t3://localhost:7101"/>
         <!--DataSource-->
         <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource"
                   value="jdbc/B_DS"/>
         <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                   value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                   value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

***IncomingPaperwork.class***

```
import com.arsivist.structure.BaseEntity;

import com.acme.integrationmodel.entity.ProjectView;
import com.acme.model.entity.listener.EntityListener;
import com.acme.model.entity.listener.IncomingPaperworkListener;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity(name = "IncomingPaperwork")
@Table(name = "INCOMINGPAPERWORKS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "INCOMINGPAPERWORK_SEQ", sequenceName = "INCOMINGPAPERWORK_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@EntityListeners( { EntityListener.class, IncomingPaperworkListener.class })
public class IncomingPaperwork extends BaseEntity
{
    private Company company;
    private ProjectView projectView;

    public IncomingPaperwork()
    {
        entityName = "IncomingPaperwork";
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "INCOMINGPAPERWORK_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company)
    {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.acme.model.entity.Company.class, cascade = { })
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANYID", nullable = false)
    public Company getCompany()
    {
        return company;
    }

    public void setProjectView(ProjectView projectView)
    {
        this.projectView = projectView;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.acme.integrationmodel.entity.ProjectView.class, cascade = { })
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECTVIEWID")
    public ProjectView getProjectView()
    {
        return projectView;
    }
}
```

***ProjectView.class***

```
import com.arsivist.structure.BaseEntityView;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect;

@Entity(name = "ProjectView")
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT * FROM ProjectView")
public class ProjectView extends BaseEntityView
{
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public ProjectView()
    {
        entityName = "ProjectView";
    }

    public ProjectView(int id, String name)
    {
        entityName = "ProjectView";

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCode(String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    public String getCode()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentailly, i just need to get projectview object within incomingpaperwork entity, i mean when fetching incomingpaperwork entity, projectview object could be load together. Thx for your consideration

Comment: i started to be curious about does nobody else read this question